# Use methods in where statements

Tags: axapta, x++

```
Table table;

    select * 
        from table
        where this.id != table.id
            && this.foo(table);
```

I am trying to make a selection from a table in X++ code.
The table is compared against a record from the table (`this`).

A record shall be added to the selection if the id of the record and another record from the table do not equal and several other conditions in `foo()` evaluate to true.
The plan is to make `this.foo(table)` evaluate the record together with each other record in the table.

When I insert the code from `foo()` directly into the call, it works just fine. However, when calling the method, it appears like `table` does not hold any reference.

What am I not understanding about the way, select statements work?
Are methods just evaluated once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use methods in the `where` expression (nor in any other part, for that matter) of the `select` statement in AX. Your example will not compile successfully.

You can either try incorporating the logic of your `foo` method in the `where` expression or iterate through the result of the `select` statement and call method `foo` for each record individually e.g.:

```
Table table;

while select table
    where table.id != this.id
{
    if (this.foo(table))
    {
        info(table.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: In simple cases you may able to select on a value computed as an expression executed on the SQL server. In that case consider using a computed column.
https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/faisalfareedaxlibrary/archive/2015/03/30/computed-columns-in-views-dynamics-ax-2012